# Magento 2 Klarna Error: 'Order line totals do not total order_amount - 17311 != 17310'

Tags: magento2, order-totals, klarna, klarnacheckout, amount

When I add a configurable product to the map and go to the second checkout step and after loading it again I reload it, I get this error: **'Order line totals do not total order_amount - 17311 != 17310'**

This error is from the method **validate** that is in the file: **`vendor/klarna/module-kp/Model/Api/Request/Builder.php`**

Code:

```
    public function validate($requiredAttributes, $type)
{
    $missingAttributes = [];
    foreach ($requiredAttributes as $requiredAttribute) {
        if (null === $this->$requiredAttribute) {
            $missingAttributes[] = $requiredAttribute;
        }
        if (is_array($this->$requiredAttribute) && count($this->$requiredAttribute) === 0) {
            $missingAttributes[] = $requiredAttribute;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($missingAttributes)) {
        throw new KlarnaApiException(
            __(
                'Missing required attribute(s) on %1: "%2".',
                $type,
                implode(', ', $missingAttributes)
            )
        );
    }
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($this->orderlines as $orderLine) {
        $total += (int)$orderLine->getTotal();
    }

    if ($total !== $this->order_amount) {
        throw new KlarnaApiException(
            __('Order line totals do not total order_amount - %1 != %2', $total, $this->order_amount)
        );
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I get into the method **validate** from here **`vendor/klarna/module-kp/Model/Api/Builder/Kasper.php`**

Code:

```
    private function generateCreateUpdate()
{
    $requiredAttributes = [
        'purchase_country',
        'purchase_currency',
        'locale',
        'order_amount',
        'orderlines'
    ];

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $this->getObject();
    $store = $quote->getStore();
    $options = array_map('trim', array_filter($this->configHelper->getCheckoutDesignConfig($store)));

    /**
     * Pre-fill customer details
     */
    $this->prefillAddresses($quote, $store);

    $address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();

    $tax = $address->getBaseTaxAmount();
    if ($this->configHelper->isFptEnabled($store) && !$this->configHelper->getDisplayInSubtotalFpt($store)) {
        $fptResult = $this->rate->getFptTax($quote);
        $tax += $fptResult['tax'];
    }

    $country = $address->getCountryId();
    if ($country === null) {
        $country = $this->directoryHelper->getDefaultCountry($store);
    }
    $this->requestBuilder->setPurchaseCountry($country)
        ->setPurchaseCurrency($quote->getBaseCurrencyCode())
        ->setLocale(str_replace('_', '-', $this->configHelper->getLocaleCode()))
        ->setOptions($options)
        ->setOrderAmount((int)$this->dataConverter->toApiFloat($address->getBaseGrandTotal()))
        ->addOrderlines($this->getOrderLines($quote->getStore()))
        ->setOrderTaxAmount((int)$this->dataConverter->toApiFloat($tax))
        ->setMerchantUrls($this->processMerchantUrls())
        ->validate($requiredAttributes, self::GENERATE_TYPE_CREATE);

    return $this;
}
```

My problem is that **`($total !== $this->order_amount) = true`**
I always have a difference of 1.

But I can't figure out why this is happening and how to fix it. Tell me, please, what could be the problem and how to fix it? If suddenly someone faced this behavior, how did you fix it?

Comment: This is really strange logic convert each line item to int. Imagine A = 0.01 and B = 0.99. Total = 1.00, (int)0.01 + (int)0.99 = 0. Total with this logic can be different from Magento Total.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I found. Today I don't have free time to describe what I did, but I can do it tomorrow morning @codedge

Comment: That would be great. Thanks @DavidYoung

Comment: @codedge you can check out my answer to this problem, I didn't describe it in code snippets because for me this is an exceptional problem that hasn't happened anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

In my case, this was due to the fact that I have a very strong modification of the current types of products: configurable and bundle, in particular.

Because of these modifications, I was getting this behavior because the pricing was changed and the price was affected by the logic that applies to my modified products.

If you do not have modified products, there are no custom product types, then my case will not suit you, but it can lead to the right solution in search of a problem.

And so, I found the problem in the class: Klarna\Core\Model\Checkout\Orderline\Items, methods: *collect* and *processItem*, *shouldSkip*.

1. In the method *collect* i had a problem that *shouldSkip* missed the products needed for pricing, therefore, I had to modify this method for the changed logic.
2. In the method *processItem* I had to change the logic that relates to getting data like: *total_amount, unit_price*
3. You need to check that in the *processItem* everything was correct so that the products that need to be skipped for pricing are skipped.

After these changes, checking in the file no longer gave an error: vendor/klarna/module-kp/Model/Api/Request/Builder.php

I want to reiterate, my case is an exception, I don't claim that this is the right way to fix the problem, but it worked for me.

Comment: Seems like a very special case, but thanks for explaining.

Comment: Yes it is @codedge

Answer (score 0):

Klarna\Core\Model\Checkout\Orderline\Items;

private function processItem($product, $item, $qtyMultiplier)

Modify the processItem function

```
private function processItem($product, $item, $qtyMultiplier)
    {
 .....

    if ($this->klarnaConfig->isSeparateTaxLine($item->getStore())) {
      ......
    } else {
       .......
          $_item['total_amount'] = $this->helper->toApiFloat(
           ($item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()) + $item->getBaseTaxAmount()
        );
        }
}
```